# Getting an "Type must derive from DependencyObject" error, when I try to to set a TargetUpdated event on a DatePicker

Tags: wpf, xaml, events, binding, datepicker

I have a XAML DatePicker that is defined as such:

```
<DatePicker x:Name="startDateDatePicker" Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource validationTemplate}"
SelectedDateChanged="window_DatePicker_SelectedDateChanged" Validation.Error="ValidationError">
    <DatePicker.SelectedDate>
        <Binding Path="startDate" Mode="TwoWay" NotifyOnValidationError="True" ValidatesOnExceptions="True" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <!-- A couple custom rules. //-->
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
         </Binding>
    </DatePicker.SelectedDate>
</DatePicker>
```

I need to attach an event handler in my code behind to `Binding.TargetUpdated` and `Binding.SourceUpdated` events on the `Binding` object in my `DatePicker.SelectedDate` object.

However, when I re-define my  tag as such:

```
<Binding Path="startDate" Mode="TwoWay" NotifyOnValidationError="True" ValidatesOnExceptions="True" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" TargetUpdated="BindingTargetUpdated" SourceUpdated="BindingSourceUpdaed">
```

I get the error messages:

> The attached property "TargetUpdated" can only be applied to types that are derived from "DependencyObject".

and

> The attached property "SourceUpdated" can only be applied to types that are derived from "DependencyObject".

What do I need to do to bind to these events?  I understand the error message, but I don't know how it relates to the `<DatePicker.SelectedDate>` item since it should be a `DependencyObject`.

Comment: don't set it against `Binding` but `DatePicker`: `<DatePicker ...  TargetUpdated="BindingTargetUpdated"`>. Against the `Binding` however you need to set `NotifyOnTargetUpdated="True"`

Comment: @dkozl  If you wouldn't mind posting an answer stating the above comment, and update the XAML code, I'll give you the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment you need to set event against `DatePicker` instead of `Binding`. Also, against the `Binding`, you need to enable both [`NotifyOnTargetUpdated`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.notifyontargetupdated(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`NotifyOnSourceUpdated`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.notifyonsourceupdated(v=vs.110).aspx) in order for the events to be raised.

```
<DatePicker ... TargetUpdated="BindingTargetUpdated" SourceUpdated="BindingSourceUpdaed">
    <DatePicker.SelectedDate>
        <Binding Path="startDate" ... NotifyOnTargetUpdated="True" NotifyOnSourceUpdated="True">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <!-- A couple custom rules. //-->
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
         </Binding>
    </DatePicker.SelectedDate>
</DatePicker>
```